# Django-orm, select last date on distinct user

Tags: postgresql, orm, django-orm

How to implement such query

`SELECT DISTINCT ON (user_id) user_id, date FROM mayak_position WHERE user_id IN ('1111', '2222') ORDER BY user_id, date DESC;`

with minimal raw `sql`, using `django-orm`

I tried many different queries, without success

`Position.objects.annotate(s=Count('user_id', distinct=True)).order_by('s')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Position.objects.filter(user_id__in=child_ids).order_by('user_id', '-date').distinct('user_id')`

[source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct)

Answer (score 0):

```
result = Position.objects.filter(user_id__in=['1111', '2222']).values('user_id','date').distinct()
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention, I do not need values, I need whole object, I think my answer fits